# Cannot delete file after performing operations

Tags: java

Unable to delete files even after closing the corresponding readers and writers. 
Permissions are present on the files
file.delete() returns false
my code

```
main(){
        try{
        File file=new File(path);// Path where the file is present
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(path); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(pathOther);
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        // Readers and writers for i/o operations
       while((String str=br.readLine())!=null){ 
       wr.write(str);                    // Copying to another file
       }
       }catch(Exception e){}
       finally{
        reader.close(); //close reader

        writer.close(); //close writer
        file.delete(); //This returns false

}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `file.exists()` right before you delete?

Comment: Don't use DataInputStream for reading text. You don't need it and it would be confusing if you did.. Using `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))` is much simpler.

Comment: The BufferedReader object initialization statement takes the form: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)))));`. Can be just `DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));`.

Comment: Side note: Since Java SE 7 java.io.File is considered legacy API. Consider to use the NIO.2 File API.

Comment: Side note: use try-with-resources to correctly close your streams

Comment: exists() returns true;

Comment: I have removed DataInputStream

Comment: @arya please provide a SSCCE.

Comment: *Never* write an empty catch block.  If you aren’t sure what to do with an exception, propagate it by adding `throws IOException` to the method’s signature.  If you don’t have that option, at least log the exception or call its [printStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--) method.

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* as to what is going on is that you close the `FileInputStream` but leave the `BufferedReader` open, which leaves something holding on to the file handle.  Then, when you try to delete the file, it returns `false` because something else has a handle on it.

Try the following code:

```
File file = new File(path);
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    // use the reader ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// now close the file
file.delete();
```

**Update:**

While testing the above code I noticed something else which could also cause the observations you were seeing.  If the file at `path` does not exist, then logically calling `file.delete` will also fail for this reason.  So you should make sure that the file actually exists before trying to delete it.  You can call `file.exists()` to check for this.

Comment: It doesnt close even now

Comment: @arya Does the file located at `path` already exist?  If not, then you won't be able to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should close the `BufferedReader` instead of the `FileReader` (the `BufferedReader` will in turn call `close()` on the `FileReader`):

So instead of:

```
reader.close(); //close reader
```

do:

```
br.close();
```

(and leave out the complete redundant comment).

Also, since `File.delete()` simply returns a Boolean and doesn't tell you *why* it failed, you can get more information by calling `Files.delete` instead:

```
try {
    Files.delete(file.toPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // e now contains information about why it can't delete.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will work call `System.gc();`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)